# How to fix broadcasting issues with numpy.vectorize()

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I am writing a custom function that I want to have behaving as if it where a numpy-function, having the ability to take in an array, and perform the same operation on every element of the input list, and returning a list of same shape with all the results.

Luckily, there is a solution for this: [`numpy.vectorize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

So I used that: I have a function that creates a model in the form of a sine wave, and it takes in two variables: one numpy list `X` containing some input values for the sine function, and one numpy list `param` that contains the four possible parameters that a sine curve can have.

```
import numpy as np
def sine(X, param):
    #Unpacking param
    A = param[0]
    P = param[1]
    Phi = param[2]
    B = param[3]

    #translating variables
    #Phi = t0/P
    f = X/P
    Y = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*(f + Phi)) + B
    return Y
```

Because only the input values `X` need the broadcasting while the all the parameters are necessary all the time, so, according to the documentation, the way to vecorise the function is as follows:

```
np_sine = np.vectorize(sine, excluded=['param']) #makes sine() behave like a numpy function
```

...so that `param` is properly excluded from vectorisation.

This method is useful, since I will be fitting this model to a dataset, which requires occasionally tweaking the parameters, meanwhile, with this method the code where I need it is only one line long:

```
CHIsqrt = np.sum(((ydata - np_sine(xdata, param))/yerr)**2)
```

where `ydata`, `xdata` and `yerr` are equally long lists of datapoints and where `param` is the list of four parameters.

Yet, the result was a broadcasting error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2831, in _vectorize_call outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (4,)
```

Since the list `param` is 4 elements long, I get that the function ignored my commands to exclude it from vectorisation. That is a problem.

I tried specifying that the end result should be a ndArray, which did not change the error.

```
np_sine = np.vectorize(sine, excluded=['param'], otypes=[np.ndarray])
```

What would be the correct way to use this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `excluded` wrong.

```
In [270]: def foo(x, param):
     ...:     a,b,c = param
     ...:     return a*x
     ...: 
In [271]: f = np.vectorize(foo, excluded=[1])  # specify by position
In [272]: f(np.arange(4),[1,3,2])
Out[272]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

For a keyword arg:

```
In [277]: def foo(x, param=[0,0,0]):
     ...:     a,b,c = param
     ...:     return a*x
     ...:
In [278]: f = np.vectorize(foo, excluded=['param'])
In [279]: f(np.arange(4),param=[1,3,2])
Out[279]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Interesting that using the string does not work for normal arguments. The documentation has an example saying `>>> def mypolyval(p, x):` which clearly has two normal arguments. Then it goes on to exclude `p` by saying `>>> vpolyval = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['p'])`. Your solution works, so the documentation is wrong.

Comment: But in the example `p` is passed as keyword parameter, `p=[1, 2, 3]`.  `vpolyval([1, 2, 3], x=[0, 1])` only works after `.excluded.add(0).  Excluded may actually be referring to the parameter in the vectorized function, not the source (though in a sense they are the same).
`

Comment: Your named `excluded` might work with `np_sine(xdata, param=param)`.